# PI945GZD audio not working

Tags: windows-xp, audio, drivers

I have an old Mercury MOBO PI945GZD. The problem is that windows XP does not detect the built-in audio device though linux detects it well and has no problems.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Windows XP doesn't always have compatible drivers. Did you download the [drivers](http://www.mercury-pc.com/downloads_list.php?productid=718) and install them?

Comment: Yeah I installed the drivers, but the problem is that the audio device doesn't even show up in the device manager.

Comment: Did you try manually adding the device with the hardware wizard?